# How to convert AC3 to AAC on Windows from the CLI

Tags: windows, powershell, audio, video, transcode

I have a large number of MKV files with AC3 tracks that I want to re-encode to include an AAC track using a script. My current approach has been to extract the AC3 track (mkvextract) and attempt to re-encode that as AAC and then merge that back in (mkvmerge). Thus far I've been able to script the extraction (MKVTools and Powershell helped there) but I cannot find a way to convert AC3 to AAC.

I've tried creating a fake MP4 file with mp4box and an "empty.h264" file (from code.google.com) but when that's presented to handbrake_cli, the short video input causes handbrake to barf. I tried a similar thing with avidemux (2.6.9) (both from the CLI with avidemux2 and GUI) but again, the very short video track causes it to fail in creating a proper new target.

If Handbrake had a "pass-through" mode for video, I'd just use that and add a second audio track that was converted from AC3 to AAC but alas handbrake doesn't do pass-through video.

What am I missing? Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I should have done 10 minutes more research and not needed to post ...

The best answer thus far appears to be ffmpeg:

## to convert a 224kbps AC3 to a 224K AAC

ffmpeg.exe -i foo.AC3 -strict -2 -ac 2 -ab 224k -codec aac foo.AAC

The challenge will be needing to build my own mkvinfo because it doesn't produce the audio bitrate in its current output that would then allow it to be captured with MKVTools and scripted. The goal will be to do something like this:

Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.AC3" | % { $f = Get-MkvInfo $*.FullName; $a = $f.Tracks[0]; ffmpeg.exe -i $*.FullName -strict -2 -ac $a.Channels -ab "" +$a.BitRate + "k" -codec aac $_.BaseName + ".aac" }

But not there yet.